# Emoji does not display in push Notification instead it display question mark or display unicode

Tags: java, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Emoji appears as a unicode characters in push notifications. i-e : if we have text like "\ud83d\ude0a". This is the code of SMILE EMOJI which displays as unicode characters or some time it display question mark in push notification.

Is there anything else need to do in code or on server side. ? Any help would be appreciated. we are using java at backend side

Json example :

```
{
   "to": "c2rMPP0eK04Ro0FJDgMflH:APA91bEydhoB0VU5W6PxJLnIRoFqOk5npEjlWzBlvdyBlX1Cp72t0bYxDyepP5Z9mWFQ2XYeUPw8PDo3QqT6Anh27wqnkBRbabTYKn0tByOZOMU6oRlrGur-efxN9_-8LlOmDZceg9Kl",
   "notification": {
      "body": "Hello",
      "title": "This is done manually. \uD83D\uDE0A"
   }
}
```

We try this things

```
byte[] emojis = user.getEmoji().getBytes();
String emojisAsString = new String(emojis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Integer emojiCodePoint = emojisAsString.codePointAt(emojisAsString.offsetByCodePoints(0,0));
char emojiChars[] = {Character.highSurrogate(emojiCodePoint), Character.lowSurrogate(emojiCodePoint)};
```

> Note : If we fire this things from postman then it is working but not
> working when it fire from backend

Comment: Could you send request to some http endpoints like mockbin.org to find the difference? Like `curl -X POST mockbin.org/request -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"emoji":"\uD83D\uDE0A"}'`. Send request by your backend and postman.

Comment: Where are your user's emoji's stored? What kind of object is the `user.getEmoji()`, is your database attempting to translate and store the emoji. You'll  need to provide more information from your code and your how your database is structured for an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this string:

```swift
"\u{D83D}\u{DE0A}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from DB, try updating your DB driver. Like if you are using MySQL, use 'mysql-connector-java:5.1.47' or higher.

Answer (score 0):

"\uD83D\uDE0A" or "\u{D83D}\u{DE0A}" is not encoded emoji.

You should encoded like `\u{` and `}`:

```
"\u{1F600} \u{1F616}"
```

Refer link:

[Emoji unicodes](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

[Unicode in iOS](https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/)

It works on playground. Check if it works on notification panel.